# Can both the values and keys of a dictionary be integers?

Tags: python

Can both the values and keys of a dictionary be integers in python? Or do I need one of them to be like a string or something?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Sure! From the python docs:

> 5.5. Dictionaries
>
> Another useful data type built into Python is the dictionary (see Mapping Types — dict). Dictionaries are sometimes found in other languages as “associative memories” or “associative arrays”. Unlike sequences, which are indexed by a range of numbers, dictionaries are indexed by keys, **which can be any immutable type; strings and numbers can always be keys**. Tuples can be used as keys if they contain only strings, numbers, or tuples; if a tuple contains any mutable object either directly or indirectly, it cannot be used as a key. You can’t use lists as keys, since lists can be modified in place using index assignments, slice assignments, or methods like append() and extend().

You can also try it out super quickly:

```
>>> dict = {1:0, 2:1}
>>> dict[1]
0
>>> dict[2]
1
```

I like one of the examples on the page as it uses a dictionary comprehension (new in 2.7+) in a way that works like a function:

```
>>> {x: x**2 for x in (2, 4, 6)}
{2: 4, 4: 16, 6: 36}
```

Since it works for *any immutable type* you can even use floats for keys:

```
>>> {x: x**2 for x in (1, 1.5, 2)}
{1: 1, 1.5: 2.25, 2: 4}
```

And again, another common immutable type in python are tuples, `(..., ..., ...)` which you can also use for keys:

```
>>> {(x,y): (x**2,y**2) for x in range(3) for y in range(2)}
{(0, 0): (0, 0), 
(0, 1): (0, 1), 
(1, 0): (1, 0), 
(1, 1): (1, 1), 
(2, 0): (4, 0), 
(2, 1): (4, 1)}
```

Comment: Hi, I just want to know which type of key do you prefer? Integer or string? Thx~

Comment: Both are completely fine and I use both depending on the circumstance. If I'm taking input from some string field (say a query string in a URL, or user input, or something from a text file), it usually makes sense to just stick with strings. But as shown in the above examples, dicts work great as a pseudo-function, in which case it may make a lot of sense to keep them as integers. I also use tuples as keys sometimes, as I work with images/matrices often so I may want a point/coordinate as the key and use a tuple there. There's uses for any key type, just use what works best for your problem.

Comment: Thanks for all the details! Recently, I just ran into a case that the keys are `integer`s, but I wonder whether should keep it or change to `string`. I appreciate your answer and help me get through this mess!

Answer (score 3):

Of course.
Just take a very simple example:
in python interpreter, input:

```
a = {1:2}  # define an dict
a[1] # get the value whose key is 1
```

then you will get out put 2.

Answer (score 0):

Any immutable can be dictionary key. like string , number, tuple etc.
the type which cannot be keys are mutable entity like list, set etc.

Answer (score -9):

<strike>The key is always a string.  It can be a number, but it is always a string.</strike>

Yes.

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

> "...can be any immutable type; strings and numbers can always be
>   keys..."

Comment: Literally from the link you posted: "Unlike sequences, which are indexed by a range of numbers, dictionaries are indexed by keys, which can be any immutable type; strings and numbers can always be keys."

Comment: @viraptor Right.  Thanks.  I'd just skimmed to confirm my assumption.  This is news to me.  I feel so much pressure when I try to answer a question; like I'm not typing fast enough and that doesn't allow for thorough research.  I guess this isn't the right job for me.

Comment: @veganaiZe You're right, quick answers are the game, and sometimes you miss. But when you do, you often want to cut your loses and delete the post. ;)

Comment: @ParticlePaul Thanks for the advice.  I'll leave my blunders for posterity to learn from my mistakes. But judging by the "disabled grey" color of this posting I think I'll be the only one learning anything from this. =]

Comment: @veganaiZe No! I can see this too, and hats off to you for leaving it here as a warning sign to others. I agree: answering new questions is way too much pressure. I prefer answering older ones.