# String formatting using integer type key in dictionary returns KeyError in Python 2,works with string type key

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, dictionary

I am working through [Google Python Class](https://developers.google.com/edu/python/dict-files#dict-formatting) and came across using key value in a dictionary for formatting a string

```
hash = {}
hash['word'] = 'garfield'
hash['count'] = 42
s = 'I want %(count)d copies of %(word)s' % hash  
# %d for int, %s for string
# 'I want 42 copies of garfield'
```

Here is my attempt.

```
my_dict={}
my_dict['1']=50
my_dict['2']=100
s='%(1)d of %(2)d' % my_dict
print s

#Output:
# 50 of 100
#Perfect!
```

It goes wrong when I use integer keys.

```
my_dict={}
my_dict[1]=50
my_dict[2]=100
s='%(1)d of %(2)d' % my_dict
print s

#Output: 
#Traceback (most recent call last):
#File "dictformat.py", line 4, in <module>
#s='%(1)d of %(2)d' % my_dict
#KeyError: '1'
```

Dictionary is formed and printed properly.I see keys of integer type are valid from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44814719/can-both-the-values-and-keys-of-a-dictionary-be-integers/44814737)

```
my_dict={}
my_dict[1]=50
my_dict[2]=100
print my_dict

#Output:
#{1: 50, 2: 100}
```

I understand there is a .format in python3 as referred in [format string using  dict Python3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5952344/how-do-i-format-a-string-using-a-dictionary-in-python-3-x) and [Python string formatting: % vs. .format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082452/python-string-formatting-vs-format)
But,I want to know what is wrong with my understanding or if integer keys should not be used for string formatting?

Comment: integer keys should not be used for when the dict keys are string

Comment: Possible duplicate of [String formatting \[str.format()\] with a dictionary key which is a str() of a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11130790/string-formatting-str-format-with-a-dictionary-key-which-is-a-str-of-a-num)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the error message `KeyError: '1'` that you get when using integer keys, the key that is searched in the dictionary has type `str`. If the `%` behaved as you intended it to, thus looking for an integer key and not finding it, the error would have been `KeyError: 1`.

Summarizing, the problem you have is related to the type of the key that `%` uses in the dictionary lookup, which is `str` and not `int`. Thus only `str` keys can be used, no automatic conversion happens between strings and integers in Python.

Answer (score 1):

### You could youse f

```
my_dict={}
my_dict[1]=50
my_dict[2]=100
s = f"{my_dict[1]} of {my_dict[2]}"
print(s)
```

Output:

```
50 of 100
[Finished in 0.2s]
```

### Other way

```
my_dict={}
my_dict[1]=50
my_dict[2]=100
s = "{} of {}".format(*my_dict.values())
print(s)
```

Output:

```
50 of 100
[Finished in 0.2s]
```